# difference between oracle 11g and 10g and 9i-detailed comparison

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

Can anyone help me understand the detailed difference between the various version of oracle db. I am not looking for vendor differences but objective differences here. Any links or site or book to understand.

Sujatha

Comment: There are docs available for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

The 'i' and 'g' part of the version name just represents either "Internet" or "Grid".

New features in Oracle 9i:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_9i#Features_introduced

New features in Oracle 10g:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/articles-10g.php

New features in Oracle 11g:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle11g/oracle_11g_new_features.htm

Comment: Oracle 12c is Released with having Cloud Capabilities.http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/cloud-control-12cr1-installation-on-oracle-linux-5-and-6.php